# Streaming mp3 on Android via gstreamer, unable to create pipeline with dynamic location

Tags: android, streaming, mp3, gstreamer

I am having some trouble creating a pipeline for remote mp3 playback. If I construct the pipeline like this:

```
data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("souphttpsrc location=https://xxxx ! mad ! autoaudiosink", &error);
```

It plays fine. However, I have to have a dynamic location, so I have to keep a reference to the source pad. This is what I have

```
data->source = gst_element_factory_make("souphttpsrc", "source"); 
decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("mad","decoder");
sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "sink");

data->pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("mp3-player");
if (!data->pipeline || !data->source || !decoder || !sink) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return NULL;
}

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data->pipeline), data->source, decoder, sink, NULL);
if (!gst_element_link_many (data->source, decoder, sink, NULL)) {
    gchar *message = g_strdup_printf("Unable to build pipeline: %s", error->message);
    g_clear_error (&error);
    set_ui_message(message, data);
    g_free (message);
    return NULL;
}
```

Then I set the location via

```
g_object_set(data->source, "location", char_uri, NULL);
```

However nothing plays. I also see the following output:

> ERROR/GStreamer+opensles_sink(17065): 0:00:00.401251335 0x6f43f520 openslessink.c:152:_opensles_query_capabilities: engine.GetInterface(IODeviceCapabilities) failed(0x0000000c)

Anyone had experience with this before? The only solution I can think of is to rebuild the pipeline everytime I want to change the source location, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
and if you later want to change the uri, wait for EOS on the bus, gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY); set the new uri and go to playing again.